# Adding Objects from Another File to an Array in a Separate File

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a better solution for adding *objects to an array*. The box objects are from a separate file and are pushed to the array one line at a time in a different file, as such:

```
function loadCols(){
collisionPoints.push(box1);
collisionPoints.push(box2);
collisionPoints.push(box3);
collisionPoints.push(box4);
collisionPoints.push(box5);
collisionPoints.push(box6);
collisionPoints.push(box7);
collisionPoints.push(box8);
collisionPoints.push(box9);
collisionPoints.push(box10);
};
```

I have tried using a for loop and concatenating the string `"box" + i` but this didn't work.
I also tried adding them to an array in the file where the objects are created but I was not able to find a way of passing the array to the main file. Although this works I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution. Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: __Syntax:__ `arr.push(element1, ..., elementN)` so `.push` can accept `n` number of `arguments`

Comment: `collisionPoints.push(box1, box2,......., boxN);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a variable from it's string name, by using the window object.

```
function loadCols(){
   for (var i=1; i<=numberOfBoxVars; i++) {
       collisionPoints.push(window["box" + i]);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, if your variable are defined within a closure and your loadCols function is defined within the same closure, you can use the "this" keyword in place of the window object.

```
(function() {
    var box1 = "1";
    var box2 = "2";
    ...

    function loadCols(){
        for (var i=1; i<=numberOfBoxVars; i++) {
           collisionPoints.push(this["box" + i]);
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for a way to use *dynamic variables* in a `for`-loop. If `box1` and so on are global variables you can get them dynamically by accessing them as property of `window`:

```
window['box'+i]
```

See here: [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you send all the objects in a JSON array you could just do this:

```
var array = JSON.parse(boxesarray);
for(var i = 0;i< array.length; i++) {
    collisionPoints.push(array[i]);
}
```

But it would require you sending all the boxes in an array, if this is not possible please post code as to why it isn't and i will adapt my anwser.

Comment: Would the load order of the javascript files make a difference? The file that creates the box objects is loaded before the main program which is load last.

Comment: Or is this created at the end of the objects file and can be accessed by the main file?

Comment: So if i understand right you have a .js that is creating the boxes and one that stores them in an array? I'll be able to give a detailed answer based on this.

Comment: Np i overlooked the fact that it was communication between two .js which as you have seen in the other answers, is easier.